# How to correctly export an iOS app icon using the iOS app icon template within Sketch?

Tags: ios, sketch-3, sketchapp

I've been struggling with exporting the iOS app icon that I created within the said template in Sketch,the first image is the design I do within the template, and the second image is when I export it, but the design that I did within the icon is missing [image: this is the design i do within the template, but when I try to export it, the R disappears.]

[image: This appears when I export the icons]

How can I export properly each Icon, preventing the design to be erased?

Answer (score 3):

all macs have sips built in
use this script, just add the name of your sourceimage

mkdir -p generated

```
sips -Z 29 --out generated/iPhoneSettings-29x29.png sourceIcon.png
sips -Z 58 --out generated/iPhoneSettings-29x29@2x.png sourceIcon.png
sips -Z 87 --out generated/iPhoneSettings-29x29@3x.png sourceIcon.png
sips -Z 80 --out generated/iPhoneSpotlight-40x40@2x.png sourceIcon.png
sips -Z 120 --out generated/iPhoneSpotlight-40x40@3x.png sourceIcon.png
sips -Z 120 --out generated/iPhoneApp-60x60@2x.png sourceIcon.png
sips -Z 180 --out generated/iPhoneApp-60x60@3x.png sourceIcon.png

sips -Z 29 --out generated/iPadSettings-29x29.png sourceIcon.png
sips -Z 58 --out generated/iPadSettings-29x29@2x.png sourceIcon.png
sips -Z 40 --out generated/iPadSpotlight-40x40.png sourceIcon.png
sips -Z 80 --out generated/iPadSpotlight-40x40@2x.png sourceIcon.png
sips -Z 76 --out generated/iPadApp-76x76.png sourceIcon.png
sips -Z 152 --out generated/iPadApp-76x76@2x.png sourceIcon.png
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Make sure that your layers are inside the artboard, in rare cases sketch fails when pasting and arranging graphics into it.
2. Maybe you selected the background for export only. Make sure the "knife"-icon ist not marked on the background. [Wrong example would look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/40C4n.png)

Besides this you can export the iTunesArtboard to all needed sizes or following the shortcuts (⇧⌘A) for selecting all Artboards and open the export dialog with (⇧⌘E) provided by "`nathan`" :)

Answer (score 0):

`Select all artboards` (⇧⌘A) and then `Export` (⇧⌘E) them.